# Can I access to facebook API with native JAVA?

Tags: java, facebook, native, java-6

I want to access Facebook throught Java Native and post my wall.

But I see it on Facebook API does not allow access to native Java for this area.

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) This is Facebook's API Docs.

Really, I'm on Facebook that can be accessed through the Java native method?

Comment: A quick [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java%20facebook%20API&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) suggests that it should be possible

Comment: Two clicks away from your link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/third-party-sdks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook API generally, and the Graph API in particular, are simple JSON/REST api based on HTTP protocol.

So you have more options, for example:

1. Call directly the API using the java.net.URL object
2. Use a java client REST library like [Jersey Client](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html)

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914015/how-to-consume-facebook-json-using-jersey-client) for detailed example about Jersey.